# Inheritance from an instance residing in non adjacent memory

Tags: c++

I dont' think it's possible, but I should ask:

I have an "object" that is mentally formed by a head and a tail that together form the body.
The head is an element of an array.

The body has a member that stores the index of the head.

```
struct head{ body* bodyP; int kind; int execution_level;}
head heads[0x1000];

struct tail{ int head_index; other_data xxxx; }
```

The struct ( or class ) "head" has also methods that I need to access from within tail.

What I would like to have is the possibility to change the name of "tail" into "body" (easy part) and being able to make "body" inherit from head just by using the head_index to refer to the head.

Comment: Does not work. But you can certainly add forwarding functions and accessors to `body` which do that indirection. BTW: Inheriting is only possible with classes, never with instances.

Comment: About the inheritance I know is on classes and not instances, but I used the expression to point out that I have already the instance where to inherit from.

Comment: In the compiler there is a position where the pointer of the child class is converted ( essentially by subtracting the size of the inherited class ) to the inherited object. Could I change something there and provide that capability ( in non standard way obvously ).

Comment: If you are open to hacking the compiler, there's no limit but your imagination, time and skill.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw this out to show the common and optional pieces.

Here is my understanding (implementation) of your problem description, not your code:

```
struct Body;  // Forward declaration.

struct Common_To_Head_Tail
{
  Body * p_body; // link to a body, hopefully it's same between head and tail.
  // Methods common to Head and Tail
};

struct Head
: public Common_To_Head_Tail
{
}

struct Tail
: public Common_To_Head_Tail
{
}

struct Body
{
  Head * p_head;
  Tail * p_tail;
};
```

**Explanation**
There is stuff that is common to the head and tail, such as pointer to the body (you can use an index if you wish).  The forward declaration is needed so the compiler can resolve the `Body` pointer.

The `Head` and `Body` inherit (share) the common stuff to head and body.

The Body *contains* a head and a tail.  The pointers (indices) are used because the parts can be located elsewhere.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the answer targets what requested, but that means that the code previously in Head should be changed in order to be used by Common_To_Head_Tail and I am asking if there is a way to avoid it just by a way of inheritance. Essentially as I understand the problem the compiler given a structure that inherits from e.g. 5 structures, has a way to convert the main pointer to the structure that inherits from the 5 structures to 5 different pointers for each different case. That is actually done just by adding some offsets.

Comment: What is asked here is the flexibility to define a different way to convert the main pointer to the inherited pointers. That could be a template function that given the main pointer and the class of the substructure gives the pointer to the substructure. So by overloading the default behaviour of it the whole concept could work seamlessly. The programmer would see mentally the structure just as a whole.